# Fn buttons are not working after suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, asus

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my Asus TUF A15 FA507RE (Ryzen 7 6800h), after suspend Fn buttons are not working, except Fn+F1(sound on/off). After reboot it works, but after suspend not. Already tried combinations: Fn+Esc, Fn+F1, etc.  Nothing helps. Laptop is using dual boot with Windows 11 Home.

Comment: Does it work with Windows?

Comment: I have no problem with it on Windows. even showkey command cannot catch fn buttons, also keyboard has special buttons to control volume and microphone, they are also inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved in newer linux kernel like in kernel 6.2 which is now included in ubuntu 23.04.
Alternative option than getting ubuntu 23.04 will be upgrading your kernel.